# Android Navigation Component - How to have bottom navigation apply to only some fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I'm working on an Android app (java) which currently only has a single activity (MainActivity) which loads four fragments via Bottom navigation. I'm using the Navigation component, this is the nav_graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.SecondFragment"
    android:label="Second"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.ThirdFragment"
    android:label="Third"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fourthFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.FourthFragment"
    android:label="Fourth"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fourth" >
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>

// .. More subfragments linked from the first four ..


</navigation>
```

What I'd like is to have a separate flow where I have an Onboarding Screen, which can link to Sign In or Sign Up. After Signing In or going through the process of Signing Up the user should return to the Home fragment with bottom navigation. The problem is, this whole second flow should not show either toolbar or bottom navigation, they should be full screen and shouldn't allow access to the bottom navigation layout.

How can I get the bottom navigation to just affect those fragments in the main app but not the screens in the sign in/sign up process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "addOnDestinationChangedListener" method of NavController in oncreate()  of your MainActivity. Here is the sample code is written in kotlin.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.splashFragment, R.id.welcomeFragment, R.id.signInFragment, R.id.signUpFragment, R.id.forgotPasswordFragment,
            R.id.forgotPasswordStepTwoFragment -> {
                mToolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                navViewBottom.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            R.id.homeFragment -> {
                mToolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                navViewBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            else -> {
                mToolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                navViewBottom.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

You have to declare  NavController in your MainActivity class for that.

```
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Here "nav_host_fragment" is fragment container in your xml file.
Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/logInFragment"
    android:name="com.android.bottomnavmultipletablayout.login.LogInFragment"
    android:label="fragment_log_in"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_log_in" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_logInFragment_to_instagramFragment"
        app:destination="@id/instagramFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/instagramFragment"
    android:name="com.android.bottomnavmultipletablayout.main.InstagramFragment"
    android:label="fragment_instagram"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_instagram" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/twitterFragment"
    android:name="com.android.bottomnavmultipletablayout.main.TwitterFragment"
    android:label="fragment_twitter"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_twitter" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/facebookFragment2"
    android:name="com.android.bottomnavmultipletablayout.main.FacebookFragment"
    android:label="fragment_facebook"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_facebook" />
```

======================================================================

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/instagramFragment"
    android:title="instagram" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/facebookFragment2"

    android:title="facebook" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/twitterFragment"
    android:title="twitter" />
```

put your id fragment you want in navigation component in menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).